# Displaying custom tags in YRI

Tags: ruby, yard

I've created some custom tags in my `.yardopts` file that look like this:

```
--name-tag optfield:"Field that is not required to be filled out by the user."
--name-tag nonfield:"Parameter that is not a field to be filled out by the user."
```

They are being displayed quite nicely when I view them in a web-browser, but when I try to view a class with `yri` I don't see my custom tags being displayed.

For example, this class

```
#This is a boring class
class Boring
    # This function is the index.
    # @param required_field [String] Required!
    # @optfield optional_argument [String] Totally not required dude.
    # @nonfield webData [WebData] Not even an option.
    def index(optional_argument = "", webData = $wedData)
    end
end
```

Get displayed as this in `yri` when I run `yri Boring#index`

```
------------------------------------------------ Method: #index (Boring)
                                               (Defined in: YardTest.rb)

    boring.index(optional_argument = "", webData = $wedData) -> Object 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    This function is the index. 

Parameters:
-----------

    (String) required_field - Required!
```

Is there a way to configure `yri` to display my custom tags?